# Ошибка при запуске пайчарм

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

[image: Сама ошибка]

Ошибка при запуске PyCharm, скачивал я его с официального сайта. Помогите пожалуйста, спасибо.

Comment: А `JDK` установлен? Похоже на его отсутствие ругается.

Comment: @Елисей Шурак чел, к вопросу не относится, но но 360total и filezilla явно говорят о том, что на компьютере вирусы, почисти комп

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, лучше всего будет переустановить программу. Но если это не поможет, скачайте **jvm.dll** самостоятельно и скиньте его в указанную в ошибке папку

Answer (score 0):

На страничке [support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003156740/comments/360000379099) дается предположение, что перепутана версия установочника между 32 и 64 битными.

При установке рекомендуется это для 64 разрядной системы. Проверьте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]